# Pyspark sum time difference between first occurrence and row

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to track the time between rank changes on a database, but I'm having a hard time doing so.

My table looks like this:

```
+-------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|user_id|       date_created|             rank|date_diff_day_float|      previous_rank|
+-------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|      1|2022-12-20 23:56:19|            rank1|               null|               null|
|      2|2022-12-26 19:28:50|            rank1|               null|               null|
|      2|2022-12-28 19:18:03|            rank2|               1.99|              rank1|
|      2|2023-01-03 14:27:40|            rank1|                5.8|              rank2|
|      3|2023-01-29 18:20:02|            rank2|               null|               null|
|      4|2023-01-10 18:27:59|            rank1|               null|               null|
|      5|2023-01-13 02:31:47|            rank2|               null|               null|
|      5|2023-01-23 23:17:40|            rank2|              10.87|               null|
|      6|2022-12-22 18:49:35|            rank2|               null|               null|
|      6|2023-01-03 18:39:34|            rank2|              11.99|               null|
|      6|2023-01-10 05:46:55|            rank1|               6.46|              rank2|
|      6|2023-01-11 17:52:01|            rank1|                1.5|               null|
|      6|2023-01-18 22:35:26|            rank1|                7.2|               null|
|      6|2023-01-23 15:31:02|            rank2|               4.71|              rank1|
|      7|2023-01-29 19:34:37|            rank1|               null|               null|
|      8|2023-03-06 18:38:19|            rank1|               null|               null|
|      9|2022-12-29 06:40:25|            rank1|               null|               null|
|      9|2023-01-25 17:27:09|            rank1|              27.45|               null|
+-------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

I managed to get the time difference in days between each log, and now I only need to sum the time between the first appearance of the previous rank and when the rank changed. Example:

User 6 first rank was rank2 on 2022-12-22 18:49:35, but his rank changed to rank1 on 2023-01-10 05:46:55, the date_difference should be the sum between all values from 2022-12-22 18:49:35 to 2023-01-10 05:46:55. So 11.99 + 6.46 = 18.45

The desired output would be something like this:

```
+-------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|user_id|       date_created|             rank|date_diff_day_float|      previous_rank|         rank_change|
+-------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|      2|2022-12-28 19:18:03|            rank2|               1.99|              rank1|        rank1=>rank2|
|      2|2023-01-03 14:27:40|            rank1|                5.8|              rank2|        rank2=>rank1|
|      6|2023-01-10 05:46:55|            rank1|              18.45|              rank2|        rank2=>rank1|
|      6|2023-01-23 15:31:02|            rank2|              13.41|              rank1|        rank1=>rank2|
+-------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
```

I used this code to group the values:

```
df = df.filter(F.col("previous_rank").isNotNull())
            .withColumn(
                "rank_change",
                F.concat_ws("=>", F.col("previous_rank"), F.col("rank")),
            )
```

I just need some help on how to get the sum working correctly

Comment: Please check my answer to see if it works as your intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check my below code. I've already commented and shown the df after each step for you to follow.

Please note that my method is based on your uploaded DF. You've already calculated the "date_diff" and "previous_rank" col. Maybe you could integrate the part you calculated these columns with my transformation below to make things shorter.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.window import *

# Create SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("rank_changes").getOrCreate()

# Create the original DF
data = [
    (1, "2022-12-20 23:56:19", "rank1", None, None),
    (2, "2022-12-26 19:28:50", "rank1", None, None),
    (2, "2022-12-28 19:18:03", "rank2", 1.99, "rank1"),
    (2, "2023-01-03 14:27:40", "rank1", 5.8, "rank2"),
    (3, "2023-01-29 18:20:02", "rank2", None, None),
    (4, "2023-01-10 18:27:59", "rank1", None, None),
    (5, "2023-01-13 02:31:47", "rank2", None, None),
    (5, "2023-01-23 23:17:40", "rank2", 10.87, None),
    (6, "2022-12-22 18:49:35", "rank2", None, None),
    (6, "2023-01-03 18:39:34", "rank2", 11.99, None),
    (6, "2023-01-10 05:46:55", "rank1", 6.46, "rank2"),
    (6, "2023-01-11 17:52:01", "rank1", 1.5, None),
    (6, "2023-01-18 22:35:26", "rank1", 7.2, None),
    (6, "2023-01-23 15:31:02", "rank2", 4.71, "rank1"),
    (7, "2023-01-29 19:34:37", "rank1", None, None),
    (8, "2023-03-06 18:38:19", "rank1", None, None),
    (9, "2022-12-29 06:40:25", "rank1", None, None),
    (9, "2023-01-25 17:27:09", "rank1", 27.45, None),
]

columns = ["user_id", "date_created", "rank", "date_diff_day_float", "previous_rank"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
# convert date_created column to timestamp type
df = df.withColumn("date_created", col("date_created").cast("timestamp"))
# Show the original DF
df.show()
# +-------+-------------------+-----+-------------------+-------------+
# |user_id|       date_created| rank|date_diff_day_float|previous_rank|
# +-------+-------------------+-----+-------------------+-------------+
# |      1|2022-12-20 23:56:19|rank1|               null|         null|
# |      2|2022-12-26 19:28:50|rank1|               null|         null|
# |      2|2022-12-28 19:18:03|rank2|               1.99|        rank1|
# |      2|2023-01-03 14:27:40|rank1|                5.8|        rank2|
# |      3|2023-01-29 18:20:02|rank2|               null|         null|
# |      4|2023-01-10 18:27:59|rank1|               null|         null|
# |      5|2023-01-13 02:31:47|rank2|               null|         null|
# |      5|2023-01-23 23:17:40|rank2|              10.87|         null|
# |      6|2022-12-22 18:49:35|rank2|               null|         null|
# |      6|2023-01-03 18:39:34|rank2|              11.99|         null|
# |      6|2023-01-10 05:46:55|rank1|               6.46|        rank2|
# |      6|2023-01-11 17:52:01|rank1|                1.5|         null|
# |      6|2023-01-18 22:35:26|rank1|                7.2|         null|
# |      6|2023-01-23 15:31:02|rank2|               4.71|        rank1|
# |      7|2023-01-29 19:34:37|rank1|               null|         null|
# |      8|2023-03-06 18:38:19|rank1|               null|         null|
# |      9|2022-12-29 06:40:25|rank1|               null|         null|
# |      9|2023-01-25 17:27:09|rank1|              27.45|         null|
# +-------+-------------------+-----+-------------------+-------------+

# Filter out all the user_id that has no rank change (1,3,4,5,7,8,9), for simplicity.
user_id_change_rank = df.where(df.previous_rank.isNotNull()).select("user_id").distinct()
df = df.join(user_id_change_rank, on="user_id")
df.show()
# +-------+-------------------+-----+-------------------+-------------+
# |user_id|       date_created| rank|date_diff_day_float|previous_rank|
# +-------+-------------------+-----+-------------------+-------------+
# |      2|2022-12-26 19:28:50|rank1|               null|         null|
# |      2|2022-12-28 19:18:03|rank2|               1.99|        rank1|
# |      2|2023-01-03 14:27:40|rank1|                5.8|        rank2|
# |      6|2022-12-22 18:49:35|rank2|               null|         null|
# |      6|2023-01-03 18:39:34|rank2|              11.99|         null|
# |      6|2023-01-10 05:46:55|rank1|               6.46|        rank2|
# |      6|2023-01-11 17:52:01|rank1|                1.5|         null|
# |      6|2023-01-18 22:35:26|rank1|                7.2|         null|
# |      6|2023-01-23 15:31:02|rank2|               4.71|        rank1|
# +-------+-------------------+-----+-------------------+-------------+

# Replace null value in "previous_rank" col with value from "rank" col
# For further use in Window function
df = df.withColumn("previous_rank",
                   when(isnull("previous_rank"), coalesce("previous_rank", "rank"))
                   .otherwise(col("previous_rank"))
                   )
df.show()
# +-------+-------------------+-----+-------------------+-------------+
# |user_id|       date_created| rank|date_diff_day_float|previous_rank|
# +-------+-------------------+-----+-------------------+-------------+
# |      2|2022-12-26 19:28:50|rank1|               null|        rank1|
# |      2|2022-12-28 19:18:03|rank2|               1.99|        rank1|
# |      2|2023-01-03 14:27:40|rank1|                5.8|        rank2|
# |      6|2022-12-22 18:49:35|rank2|               null|        rank2|
# |      6|2023-01-03 18:39:34|rank2|              11.99|        rank2|
# |      6|2023-01-10 05:46:55|rank1|               6.46|        rank2|
# |      6|2023-01-11 17:52:01|rank1|                1.5|        rank1|
# |      6|2023-01-18 22:35:26|rank1|                7.2|        rank1|
# |      6|2023-01-23 15:31:02|rank2|               4.71|        rank1|
# +-------+-------------------+-----+-------------------+-------------+

# Calculated the sum based on user_id and previous_rank (not rank)
# since we want to calculate the sum all the way to when the rank change, using Window function
# Also the max_date_created
window_spec = Window.partitionBy("user_id", "previous_rank").orderBy("date_created")\
    .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
df = df.withColumn("sum_date_diff_day_float", sum("date_diff_day_float").over(window_spec)) \
        .withColumn("max_date_created", max("date_created").over(window_spec))
df.show()
# +-------+-------------------+-----+-------------------+-------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
# |user_id|       date_created| rank|date_diff_day_float|previous_rank|sum_date_diff_day_float|   max_date_created|
# +-------+-------------------+-----+-------------------+-------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
# |      2|2022-12-26 19:28:50|rank1|               null|        rank1|                   1.99|2022-12-28 19:18:03|
# |      2|2022-12-28 19:18:03|rank2|               1.99|        rank1|                   1.99|2022-12-28 19:18:03|
# |      2|2023-01-03 14:27:40|rank1|                5.8|        rank2|                    5.8|2023-01-03 14:27:40|
# |      6|2023-01-11 17:52:01|rank1|                1.5|        rank1|                  13.41|2023-01-23 15:31:02|
# |      6|2023-01-18 22:35:26|rank1|                7.2|        rank1|                  13.41|2023-01-23 15:31:02|
# |      6|2023-01-23 15:31:02|rank2|               4.71|        rank1|                  13.41|2023-01-23 15:31:02|
# |      6|2022-12-22 18:49:35|rank2|               null|        rank2|                  18.45|2023-01-10 05:46:55|
# |      6|2023-01-03 18:39:34|rank2|              11.99|        rank2|                  18.45|2023-01-10 05:46:55|
# |      6|2023-01-10 05:46:55|rank1|               6.46|        rank2|                  18.45|2023-01-10 05:46:55|
# +-------+-------------------+-----+-------------------+-------------+-----------------------+-------------------+

# Select the desired row (max_date_created ~ date that rank change) and column (drop some unecessary cols)
df = df.filter(col("date_created") == col("max_date_created"))\
    .withColumn("rank_change", concat(col("previous_rank"), lit("=>"), col("rank"))).orderBy("date_created")
df = df.drop("date_diff_day_float", "max_date_created")

df.show()
# +-------+-------------------+-----+-------------+-----------------------+------------+
# |user_id|       date_created| rank|previous_rank|sum_date_diff_day_float| rank_change|
# +-------+-------------------+-----+-------------+-----------------------+------------+
# |      2|2022-12-28 19:18:03|rank2|        rank1|                   1.99|rank1=>rank2|
# |      2|2023-01-03 14:27:40|rank1|        rank2|                    5.8|rank2=>rank1|
# |      6|2023-01-10 05:46:55|rank1|        rank2|                  18.45|rank2=>rank1|
# |      6|2023-01-23 15:31:02|rank2|        rank1|                  13.41|rank1=>rank2|
# +-------+-------------------+-----+-------------+-----------------------+------------+
```